# How to create an empty datatable with columns names and then append datatables to it?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

First I want to create an empty datatable with column names but it fails:

```
data <- data.table(va, vb, vc)

> Error in data.table(va, vb, vc) : object 'va' not found
```

Second I want to append datatable to it but it fails too :

```
data2 <- data.table(va=c(-1,0,1), vb=c(-1,0,1), vc=c(-1,0,1))
data2
   va vb vc
1: -1 -1 -1
2:  0  0  0
3:  1  1  1
merge(data2,data2)

> Error in merge.data.table(data2, data2) : 
      Can not match keys in x and y to automatically determine appropriate `by` parameter. Please set `by` value explicitly.
```

Apparently the function can't identify the `by` parameters with two identical datatables. Any idea?

Comment: "object va" not found is because R assumes it is a variable name and there is no existing variable in your workspace named `va`

Comment: To create an empty data.table use (assuming all columns numeric): `data=data.table(va=numeric(), vb=numeric(), vc=numeric())`

Comment: Dynamically growing things in a loop (which is what it sounds like you're doing) is a bad idea in R.

Comment: This question is obsolete, `merge(data2,data2)` defaults to all (shared) keys just fine in data.table v1.11.x. I guess this was not implemented back in v1.9.6 (2016).

Comment: @Frank : could you lead me to an article that explains why you should not grow tables dynamically? I can't fine a good one.

Comment: @tamarad Chapter 2 of the R Inferno (free here https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is what folks usually point to, where it mentions "fragmenting memory" and slowness as side effects. This applies to vectors, arrays and tables. I think the one exception is that growing lists is okay, as mentioned in comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801035/growing-a-list-with-variable-names-in-r

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To **create an empty `data.table`** use (assuming all columns are numeric):

```
library(data.table)    
data <- data.table(va=numeric(), vb=numeric(), vc=numeric())
data
```

which results in:

```
> data
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: va,vb,vc
```

To **do a self join over all columns** use (even though the result is the same ;-):

```
data2 <- data.table(va=c(-1,0,1), vb=c(-1,0,1), vc=c(-1,0,1))
data2
merge(data2, data2,by=names(data2))
```

The reason why you have to specify the `by` parameter is the documented semantics of `merge`:

> by:
>
> A vector of shared column names in x and y to merge on. This defaults
>   to the shared key columns between the two tables. If y has no key
>   columns, this defaults to the key of x.

Since you don't have set any keys the "join" columns to merge the data tables are unclear.

There is no implicit "use all column" semantics if you omit the `by` parameter (as cited above the shared key columns are taken).

To **append all rows** of a data.table to another one you use `rbind` ("row bind") instead of `merge`:

```
data3 <- rbind(data2, data2)
data3
```

Which results in:

```
> data3
   va vb vc
1: -1 -1 -1
2:  0  0  0
3:  1  1  1
4: -1 -1 -1
5:  0  0  0
6:  1  1  1
```

Comment: In 1.11.x, `merge` now uses shared key columns, where possible. *"There is no implicit "use all column" semantics if you omit the `merge(..., by)` parameter"* is no longer true; I guess it was not implemented back in 2016 (v1.9.6). Could you correct your answer?

Answer (score 28):

To create an empty data.table, you can start from an empty matrix:

```
library(data.table)
data <- setNames(data.table(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 3)), c("va", "vb", "vc"))
data
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: va,vb,vc
```

Then you can use `rbindlist` to append new data.table to it:

```
data2=data.table(va=c(-1,0,1), vb=c(-1,0,1), vc=c(-1,0,1))
data2
   va vb vc
1: -1 -1 -1
2:  0  0  0
3:  1  1  1
rbindlist(list(data, data2))
   va vb vc
1: -1 -1 -1
2:  0  0  0
3:  1  1  1
```

Or even simpler, the following also works:

```
data <- data.table()
data <- rbindlist(list(data, data2))
data
   va vb vc
1: -1 -1 -1
2:  0  0  0
3:  1  1  1
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer... So much flexibility in this...

Comment: To make it a complete `data.table` way than you can use `setnames` instead of `setNames`

Answer (score 8):

Another way to create an empty data.table with defined column names but without having to define data types:

```
data <- data.table(1)[,`:=`(c("va", "vb", "vc"),NA)][,V1:=NULL][.0]
```

This does the following

1. `data.table(1)`: Create a non-`NULL` data.table to which you can add columns

   - Has a one column `V1` with one row. Value `1`
   - You can use any value (other than `NULL`) in the place of `1`
2. `` [,`:=`(c("va", "vb", "vc"),NA)] ``: Add columns `va`, `vb`, `vc`

   - Now has four columns (starting with `V1`) and one row. value `1,NA,NA,NA`
   - Any non-`NULL` value can be substituted for NA
3. `[,V1:=NULL]`: Remove the `V1` column
4. `[.0]`: Return a blank row

   - You can actually use [.*n*] where *n* is any integer.

If you don't like the black magic of `[.0]` you can also use

```
data <- data.table(1)[,`:=`(c("va", "vb", "vc"),NA)][,V1:=NULL][!is.na(va)]
```

---

Edit several years later:
note that these columns are initially `class`ed as `logical` (for the `NA` example as above). The column classes are normally coerced into the classes of the columns of any appended data, but this appears to fail with Date data.

```
> alldata[,lapply(.SD,class)] # 0-row data seeded with NA in each column as above
        va      vb      vc       vd
1: logical logical logical  logical
> filedata[,lapply(.SD,class)] # lines of real data that you are trying to merge
          va        vb      vc   vd
1: character character integer Date
> rbindlist(list(alldata,filedata))
Error in rbindlist(list(alldata, filedata), use.names = FALSE) : 
  Class attribute on column 4 of item 2 does not match with column 4 of item 1.
```

To navigate around this error, one solution is to use [@R Yoda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376507/4228193) with that column declared as e.g. `vd=as.Date(character(0), origin = "1970-01-01")`

Note that this error was reported to the data.table github repo [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5344) for this specific use-case. It had generally been reported [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3911) previously.

Comment: Interesting black magic. How did you come up with `.0`? Never seen it before